# How to hide google chart tooltip action based on selection?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I need to hide tooltip action based on selected item, but JS console shows that function `getSelection` is undefined.

```
        chart.setAction({
        id: 'someID',
        text: 'Tooltip action text',
        visible: function () {

            var senderType = DataTable.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 2)
            if (senderType == "1")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        },
        action: function () {
            var senderType =  DataTable.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 2)
            if (senderType == "1")
                DoSomething( DataTable.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 2));

        }
    });
```

Action itself works fine and if I return just true or false, then all is working fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple.

Function `visible` for some reason is called twice. I just added check if selections first row is not `undefined`.

```
            if (typeof(chart.getSelection) == 'undefined')
                return false;
            if (typeof (chart.getSelection()[0]) == 'undefined')
                return false;
```

If there is some better way - please share.

Comment: If the chart has no selected elements (or you click the same element twice in a row), the `getSelection` mothod will return an empty array.  What you have will work, but checking `chart.getSelection().length > 0` is sufficient.